# custom table in user model laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using oauth2 and my table users is "coUsers" . I added this in my User Model

App\User

```
protected $table = 'coUsers';
public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->pass;
    }
```

AuthController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'usuario' => 'required|string|email',
        'clave' => 'required|string',
        //'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = [
        'usuario' => $request->get('usuario'),
        'password' => $request->get('clave'),
    ];

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);

    $token->save();

    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse($tokenResult->token->expires_at)->toDateTimeString()
    ]);
}

public function firstLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'usuario' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
        'clave' => 'required|string',
        'nuevaClave' => 'required|string'
    ]);

    $user = User::where('usuario', $request['usuario'])
                ->where('clave', $request['clave'])
                ->first();

    $user->clave = bcrypt($request['nuevaClave']);
    $user->first_login = false;
    $user->save();
    return response()->json([
        $user->toArray()
    ]);
}
```

Auth login works OK, but I want to use User::where in firstLogin.... I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "usuario" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where "usuario" = ...
>                                                           ^ (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from "users" where "usuario" = xxxxx@gmail.com) in file \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 669

Look in the users table instead of using the table that I indicated in the model.

Comment: Could you plz provide more informations about where you're calling User::where... ?

Comment: Yes, I edited my question. Thank you

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change `'usuario' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',` to `'usuario' => 'required|string|email|unique:coUsers',` in your `firstLogin` method

You may also change this `'unique:users'` in `validator` method inside your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController`

```
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users']
```

to

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:coUsers'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
}
```